# ImageMagick : get image width return undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, imagemagick

im using easyImage moudel built on top of ImageMagick i'm trying to store image width in a variable but it return undefined

```
var width = null;

var imageWidth = easyimg.info(fileSrc).then(function(file){ // get the width

console.log(file.width);
width = file.width;

}); 
console.log(width);
```

first console it gives me a number but the second one outside the function is undefined i also tried return value but not working .

Comment: Next time, please put imagemagick in your tags. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since easyimg.info(...) is asyncronous

```
console.log(width);
```

is run before you assign a value to variable width

Comment: should i put my code inside callback function ?? show me example if you can

Comment: Yes just put the code inside the callback or just create a function outside and call it from within the callback with param width

Answer (score 1):

EasyImage is a promise-based image processing module. Your function inside `then` is not executed immediately but only after the file has been successfully processed.